# Loop through php array issues

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I'm sure I've been staring at this WAY too long, so asking for a lifeline.

I'm pulling data from a MySQL database. In particular this:

```
$category[] = "$row->category";
$issue[] = "$row->issue";
```

I need to cycle through the data. There are 6 categories in total and could be any number of issues for each category.

I would like to echo the data for each row as follows:

```
Category 1
Issue 1a
Issue 1b
Issue 1c

Category 2
Issue 2a
Issue 2b

Category 3
Issue 3a
Issue 3b
Issue 3c
Issue 3d
Issue 3e
```

I probably need more sleep, but I cannot seem to cycle through this properly. Any help would be appreciated.

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM project INNER JOIN data1 ON project.p_key = data1.p_key_project WHERE data1.p_key_project=? AND data1.archived=? ORDER BY data1.category, data1.updated DESC");
$stmt->execute(array($passed_key,'n'));

while ($row = $stmt->fetchObject()) {
$cust[] = "$row->cust_name";
$p_key[] = "$row->p_key";
$pid[] = "$row->pid";
$account_key[] = "$row->account_key";
$p_key_data1[] = "$row->p_key_data1";
$date[] = "$row->date";
$updated[] = "$row->updated";
$category[] = "$row->category";
$ryg[] = "$row->ryg";
$issue[] = "$row->issue";
$proposed_resolution[] = "$row->proposed_resolution";
$action_items[] = "$row->action_items";
$owner[] = "$row->owner";
$status[] = "$row->status";
}
```

Comment: in the querry order by category,issue. in the output check for when category changes

Answer (score 0):

PDO version based on updates we've been talking about:

assume $issues is a multidimensional array of issues and categories you could do. i.e. `$issue[] = "$row->issue, $row->category";`

```
$numOfItems = count($issue); //counts number of times for should be run
   for ($row = 0; $row < $numofItems; $row++) { 
     echo $issues[$row][$row] . "</br>";
     $i=0;
     while ($issues[$i][$row] == $issues[$row][$row]) {
      echo $issues[$i][$row] . "</br>";
      $i++;
    } }
```

This is freehand - but it should work

OLD ANSWER BELOW

If you copy and paste the Database Schema (or a part of it) that would be helpful to see how Categories and Issues are related. Not seeing the exact relationship, I think this is probably how your database is structured

so lets that `$category[] = "$row->category";` populates categories; now you have to match issues to each category. I assume that a row in your database has a category assigned to each issue. i.e. your database looks like

```
ID | Category | Issue 
1  | Pizza    | Bad
2  | Pizza    | Good
```

If thats the case then below should work

```
foreach ($category as $key => $value) {
    $query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM project INNER JOIN data1 ON project.p_key = data1.p_key_project WHERE data1.p_key_project=? AND data1.archived=? AND data1.category='$value' ORDER BY data1.category, data1.updated DESC"); //value is the individual category
    echo $value . "</br>";
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
            echo $row['issue'] . '</br>';
        }
    echo "</br>"; //adds an extra space between categories
}
```

Updated to include your specific query

Comment: updated original with samples of what each result should look like. But issues ( and each line item associated) will be unique

Comment: I know you are using PDO, but MySQLi should still work.  in the mysqli_query copy and past your sql query and add in "AND data1.category = '$value' - and this should work....i know theres probably another way with PDO but this should also work in conjunction with PDO...I amended my answer to include your exact Query assuming data1 has the category table

Comment: Thanks Usman, I think I have all the data required in the associated arrays, so just a matter of cycling through them the right way. I do not think I need another database dip .... and not MySQLi for various reasons. I think it is a couple of for loops maybe, just cannot seem to get it straight. Appreciate your help !!

Comment: I want that reputation! lol...well it seems like all you need is to create a multidimensional array when you are grabbing issues, so that it grabs issues AND the categoryid... try this $issue[] = "$row->issue, $row->category"; - if that creates a multidimensional array you can just loop through that

Comment: got an example of how to loop through it ?

Comment: output:M
r
g
g
i
l
A
o
s
i
C
C
e
e
l

Comment: Thats a weird output...maybe $issue[] = "$row->issue", "$row->category";

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139443/discussion-between-usman-shahid-and-vacek).